# Are there any countable Hausdorff connected spaces?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, separation-axioms

Do countable Hausdorff connected topological spaces exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46986/countable-connected-hausdorff-space/46990#46990) (MathOverflow) for references to some non-trivial examples.

Answer (score 5):

Trivially yes, a singleton for example ;).  Non-trivial examples abound, for example ''A countable connected Hausdorff space'' by Brown, in Bull. Amer. Math. Soc., 59 (1953) p. 367.

Comment: My mistake!I didn' t mean the trivial example

Comment: I assume "countable" here means countably infinite.

Comment: I thought so :).  I added a reference that you might find interesting.  In general these things are quite strange.  But I guess you can get more out of Theo's link.

Comment: Yes indeed .Is there another meaning that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I believe Qiaochu is only implying that my 'singleton' response was not a valid example.

Comment: @t.spero: some people use "countable" to mean "at most countable."

Answer (score 5):

[$\pi$-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org) is an online encyclopedia of topological spaces inspired by Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in Topology*. It lists the following countable, connected, Hausdorff spaces. You can learn more about any of them by visiting the [search result](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Countable%2BConnected%2B%24T_2%24).

Gustin's Sequence Space

Irrational Slope Topology

Prime Integer Topology

Relatively Prime Integer Topology

Roy's Lattice Space