# how to show a countable space is totally disconnected for any metric?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose X is countable.
We need to show that for any metric d on X the space (X,d) is totally disconnected.

It is true that any subset of a countable set is countable. so, divide the space until its components such a way it is the element we use for counting. thus, X is totally disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 facts :

1. Any connected metric space with at least 2 points is uncountable. This has been asked a few times here on MSE (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96541/connected-metric-spaces-with-at-least-2-points-are-uncountable), for instance)
2. Any subset of a countable space is countable.