# Integers are geodesic

Tags: geometric-group-theory

Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ the integers. Is this considered a geodesic metric space under the usual metric? Why? given $n,m$ integers, we would require to have a map $f: [0,c] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(0)=n$ and $f(c)=m$ and also $f$ must be a quasi-isometric embedding. But how can this be?

Comment: No such map $f$ can be continuous, so no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to even contemplate geodesics between points $x$ and $y$ of a metric space $M$, there must be some path from $x$ to $y$, i.e., a continuous function $\gamma: [0,1] \rightarrow M$ with $\gamma(0) = x$, $\gamma(1) = y$.  In particular a geodesic metric space is certainly path-connected.

The integers under the standard metric form an infinite, discrete topological space, so no two distinct points can be connected by a path.  So the answer is **no**.  For that matter, [no metric on the integers makes them connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96541/connected-metric-spaces-with-at-least-2-points-are-uncountable), so there is really no hope here.

Moreover, since no countably infinite metric space can be geodesic, being geodesic is certainly *not* a quasi-isometry invariant.