# Regarding a metric space is compact, complete, connected

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness, complete-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Which is/are true?

1) if $X$ is  countable, then  $X$ is not connected.

2) If $X$ is countable, bounded and complete, then  $X$ is compact.

3) if $X$ is compact, then $d$ is bounded.

My attempt : 
Option (  1) is false :  if we consider singleton set is $X$.

For option 2)  we know that if a space is complete and totally bounded then it is compact. 
So I think 2 is true option

3) we know that the property of a metric space depends on the whole set and the metric and in a metric space a compact set is closed and bounded. 
So I think option 3 is true.

Please help to solve this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If finite sets are countable, then you're right. Otherwise, this statement is [true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96541/connected-metric-spaces-with-at-least-2-points-are-uncountable).
2. This is false too. Take a countable set with the discrete metric.
3. Fix $x_0\in X$. The map$$\begin{array}{ccc}X&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\x&\mapsto& d(x,x_0)\end{array}$$is continuous and therefore (since $X$ is compact) it is bounded. If $R$ is an upper bound of its range, then $X$ is contained on the closed ball centered at $x_0$ with radius $R$ and therefore it is bounded.

Comment: # Santos  singleton set is not counble. Why?

Comment: If singleton is not countable then how can you say that option 1 is false?

Comment: The most usual definition of countable set is: a set $C$ is countable if there is a bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $C$. But, of course, if the definition of countable set that you wrotk with includes finite sets, then you're right. Concerning my statement that assertion 1. is false, did you notice that the word “false” in my answer is a link? I've edited my answer.

Comment: Yes sir, I see your link. After seeing your link  I assert that option 1 is right option. Am I right sir?

Comment: @Golambiswas As I wrote in my previous comment, this depends upon the defintion of countable that you use. So, please tell me how is it that you define “countable set”.

Comment: Yes sir, I use same definition of countable set.

Comment: @Golambiswas The same as mine?

Comment: Yes sir. I agree on your definition. I use this definition as you mentioned.

Comment: @Golambiswas Then a singleton is **not** countable.

Comment: Then tell me your opinion about the option 1  is false or correct? Plz

Comment: @Golambiswas Given the definition of countable that we both use, the first option is false. That's what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: But sir , a singleton set is a finite set. And a finite set is countable. Am I write sir?

Comment: @Golambiswas No, you are wrong. There is no bijection between a finite set and $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Okkk sir. Thank  you so much.

Comment: @ Santos sir, can you give an example regarding option (1)?

Comment: @Golambiswas No, I cannot. I got confused and I wrote that the statement is false, but it is true (the link is correct, though). I've edited my answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: I told this when you given the link.. Okk sir thanku so much.

Comment: @Golambiswas Now I see that you did that. Again, I'm sorry.