# Is there a simply connected region with only two (or 1<N<$+\infty$) boundary points?

Tags: complex-analysis, connectedness

My textbook states the Riemann mapping theorem as follows:

> If D is a simply-connected domain on the extended complex plane that has at least two boundary points ... (translated)

I'm wondering what a simply-connected region with only two boundary points would be.

---

Definition of simply-connected domain:

> *For every simple closed curve C in domain D, all points in the interior of C are also in D,* where the "interior" means: a simple closed curve in the plane divides the plane into two regions, one exterior, one interior.

What I know:

1. There are both points belonging and not belonging to the set in any neighborhood of the boundary point.
2. The complement of a simply-connected region is a connected region.

PS. I major in physics. I don't know much about this problem and the translation maybe not very clear. The textbook is specially written for physics students as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is simple connectivity defined in your textbook? Do you already know that $X={\mathbb C}\setminus \{0\}$ is not simply-connected? If not, what are other theorems about simply-connected domains that you know and that would show that $X$ is not simply-connected?

Comment: @MoisheKohan It's defined as follows: for every simple closed curve $C$ in domain $D$, all points in the interior of $C$ are also in $D$. I know $X$ is not simply-connected if $z=\infty$ is not taken into account. I'm a physics major, and I don't know much about this. The textbook is specially written for physics students as well.

Comment: Ok, then edit the question to make it clear what you know and what you do not know. Include the definition of the "interior" of a simple closed curve. Incidentally, the definition they gave you is quite horrible since it hinges upon Jordan curve theorem, which is a nontrivial result.

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Functions of a Complex Variable (2nd Edition), Zhenjun Yan, Press of USTC. It's written in Chinese. (《复变函数》严镇军)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. If the region has finitely many boundary boundary points, then the boundary is equal to the complement of the region. But

- The complement of a simply-connected region is connected.
- [Connected metric spaces with at least 2 points are uncountable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96541/42969)

Comment: Is something wrong here? Please let me know!

Comment: Don't know, but maybe due to EoQS. Incidentally, it's unclear if OP knows why the first item holds (there are so many competing definitions of simple connectivity used in CA textbooks).

Comment: Why is the boundary equal to the complement of the region if the region has finitely many boundary points?

Comment: @BetaGem: Otherwise the complement would contain an open disk, and then every line from the center of that disk to some point in the region would meet the boundary somewhere.

Comment: @MartinR I still don't understand. What's the contradiction if the lines meet the boundary?

Comment: @BetaGem: Because you get infinitely many boundary points, one for every direction of such lines.

Comment: @MartinR I see. It seems that I really lack knowledge in this field. Thank you.

Comment: @BetaGem: Which part is still unclear?

Comment: The picture seems clear now, but I don't know how to express it strictly in mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

There are no simple connected domains with 2 boundary points, but the complete extended complex plane is a simple connected domain without boundary points. The extended complex plane with one point removed is a simple connected domain with one boundary point. Those are all the examples. So my guess is that your textbook is using "with at least two boundary points" as a shortcut of "different from the whole extended complex plane or the extended complex plane with a point removed"